# Executing shell command and reading its output on a C program

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am trying to create a function which takes a shell command as an argument , uses fork to spawn a new process which executes the command. I also want to redirect the standard output of the command so the caller of the function can read it using a FILE* pointer.

```
static FILE* runCommand(char* command){
    int pfd[2];

    if(pipe(pfd)<0)     
        return NULL;

    if(pid=fork()==0){ //child
        close(pfd[0]);
        dup2(pfd[1],1); //redirect output to pipe for writing

        execlp(command,(char*)0);
    }

    close(pfd[1]);

    //return a file pointer/descriptor here?
```

}

I am not sure how to return a file pointer which can be used to read the output of the command. Also is that the correct way to execute a command on the shell?

ps. I read about popen but there is a good reason I can't use it, thus I have to implement this functionality myself.

Thank you

Comment: It seems popen is calling malloc ( I can see that cause I have overrided malloc ) and that complicates things for my project. That's why I'd prefer to not call popen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One bug in that code is that you assign to a variable `pid` that is not declared anywhere. And pid will always be 1 in the parent, because the code as written is equivalent to `pid=(fork()==0)` rather than `(pid=fork())==0`.

You should also close pfd[1] after the dup2 call. And for good measure, check for errors from dup2 and execlp.

The answer to your real question is to use `fdopen`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fdopen` to associate an existing file descriptor with a `FILE *` object. Everything else looks pretty good.